# Change Detection With Active_record Dirty: Before @example.update(model_params)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble getting the dirty module to work.

My method starts in the controller, before the update action is called, I want to see if the model has changed. Like so:

```
def update  
 respond_to do |format|
  #If the zipcode changes on an update - reset shipping options       
  if @order_preview.zip_different?
    if @order_preview.update(order_preview_params) 
      #Do Something
    ...
    end

  #if the zipcode doesn't change on update - assume only cart contents were altered
  else
     if @order_preview.update(order_preview_params) 
     #Do something else

     ...
     end
  end     
end
```

The zip_different model looks like this:

```
def zip_different?
    self.zip_changed?
end
```

Seems straight forward enough, but it returns false every time.  **Do I have to place the check AFTER the `@order_preview.update(order_preview_params)`**  I thought by that point, the persistence would be lost.

Comment: `self.zip_changed?`. should that be `self.zip_changed` .

Comment: nah zip_changed? returns true or false (only false in my case) -- zip_changed will raise undefined method error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the model attributes from the params before checking the dirty state:

```
@order_preview.attributes = order_preview_params

if @order_preview.zip_changed?
  ...
else
  ...

if @order_preview.save
  ...
else
  ...
```

Comment: Is it requried to set the params every time you use dirty?

Comment: Yes. The dirty detection only looks at the attributes on the model, not the data in the HTTP request params.